# cant get postgresql work on hiroku server

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku

people told me to write all the trace back so.. im sorry that it is so long :|.
hope you can help me out here. i was using **sqlite** in development. when i put it into production i put in heroku and switched to **postgresql** the mment i i switched that happened.
first there is the exception and after i copy pasted the pythn code.

please help :)

```
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-20 23:42:39,903] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906226+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906228+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906234+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906235+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906236+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_posts" does not exist
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906236+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM blog_posts
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906237+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906237+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906237+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906238+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906238+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906238+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906239+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906239+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906239+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906240+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906240+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 100, in get_all_posts
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:     posts = BlogPost.query.all()
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3346, in all
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:     return list(self)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3508, in __iter__
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906242+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3533, in _execute_and_instances
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906243+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906243+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906243+00:00 app[web.1]:     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906243+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906243+00:00 app[web.1]:     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:     ret = self._execute_context(
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.raise_(
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "blog_posts" does not exist
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906245+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM blog_posts
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906246+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906246+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906247+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT blog_posts.id AS blog_posts_id, blog_posts.title AS blog_posts_title, blog_posts.subtitle AS blog_posts_subtitle, blog_posts.date AS blog_posts_date, blog_posts.body AS blog_posts_body, blog_posts.img_url AS blog_posts_img_url, blog_posts.author_id AS blog_posts_author_id 
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906247+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM blog_posts]
2021-12-20T23:42:39.906247+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

thats my code in python

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL1")
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users': 'sqlite:///users.db'
}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
gravatar = Gravatar(app,
                    size=100,
                    rating='g',
                    default='retro',
                    force_default=False,
                    force_lower=False,
                    use_ssl=False,
                    base_url=None)


##CONFIGURE TABLES

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "blog_posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")
    comments = relationship("Comment", back_populates="parent_post")

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")
    comments = relationship("Comment", back_populates="comment_author")

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("blog_posts.id"))

    parent_post = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="comments")

    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    comment_author = relationship("User", back_populates="comments")
```

Comment: why is it that you're saying Postgres and you have code with reference to a filesystem SQLite database? SQLite cannot work on Heroku, afaik, because Heroku doesn't support guarantee of access of anything on the filesystem.

Comment: heh :| basically that's what they teach me at the boot camp. I managed to solve it by just create new database based on postgres in the server. thanks i slept on the problem and solved it the only problem is that I slept for two hours because of it heh :)